# Why does "Magento commerce" remove previous version of Magento c.e website from the official website?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2

I was looking for a previous version of Magento CE 1.9.1, but there is only Magento CE > 2.0 on the official website. There're 95% Magento websites still on the older version.

Why are the previous versions removed from the official website?

Comment: because Magento is awful

Comment: if you're right at the start of a project and have the choice not to use magento back away now, this is just the tip of the magento iceberg that will drive you mad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find every release starting with `1.1.1` in this unofficial repo: 
https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/tags

Comment: You can go down to 1.0.0 on the official Magento website ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can find the 1.x versions (down to the first one 1.0.0) on the official website https://magento.com/tech-resources/download in the **Release Archive tab.**

Answer (score 3):

Magento won't remove its previous version from its website, it just segregates into in Download and Release archive section.